# Longest common substring in 3 string input

Tags: string, algorithm, substring

I'm doing this question for my own practice and not sure if I'm doing in the most efficient way. Please share any ideas on improving efficieny and my algorithm.

My Algorithm:

- Create three suffix array for each corresponding string.
- Creating suffix array: One loop to traverse the string and after that sort the vector using stl library so I believe this preprocessing of string is O(n*nlogn). (How should I reduce the complexity here?)
- Then traverse any vector and compare the suffix string of all three input strings and compare with maximum you've.

Code:

```csharp
string commonLongestSubstring(string str1, string str2, string str3)
{
    int length1 = str1.length(), length2 = str2.length(), length3 = str3.length();
    if (length1 == 0 || length2 == 0 || length3 == 0)
        return "";

    vector<string> suffixArray1 = getSuffixArray(str1);
    vector<string> suffixArray2 = getSuffixArray(str2);
    vector<string> suffixArray3 = getSuffixArray(str3);

    string longestCommon = "";  
    for (int i = 0; i < suffixArray1.size() && i < suffixArray2.size() && i < suffixArray3.size(); ++i) {
        string prefix = commonPrefix(suffixArray1[i], suffixArray2[i], suffixArray3[i]);
        if (longestCommon.length() < prefix.length())
            longestCommon = prefix;
    }

    return longestCommon;
}    

string commonPrefix(string a, string b, string c)
{
    string prefix;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length() && i < b.length() && i < c.length(); ++i) {
        if (a[i] != b[i] || a[i] != c[i])
            break;
        prefix = prefix + a[i];
    }

    return prefix;
} 

vector<string> getSuffixArray(string str)
{
    int length = str.length();
    vector<string> suffixesContainer;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        suffixesContainer.push_back(str.substr(i, length));
    }

    sort(suffixesContainer.begin(), suffixesContainer.end());

    return suffixesContainer;
}
```

Doubts:

- How to reduce the complexity of part where I'm preprocessing the suffixArray?
- This is for three strings but what if problem size increased to n-strings then this algorithm won't work because then I've to create n-suffixArrays. So how usually we handle that case?
- General ideas on how usually we work on solving this type of questions(substrings)?

(Language no barrier)

Comment: It looks like there is a dedicated wikipedia page (with an algorithm section and pseudo-code - that should help for the complexity part) : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [generalized suffix array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_suffix_tree) to solve [k-common substring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem)

Answer (score 0):

Give three strings a,b,c an algorithm like this can be solve in O(length(a) * length(b) * length(c)).

The following algorithm can be rewrite using dinamic programming to improve the performance, but it is a good starting point:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println(lcs("hello", "othello", "helicopter"));
}

private static String lcs(final String a, final String b, final String c) {
    return recursive_lcs(a, b, c, "");
}

private static String recursive_lcs(final String a, final String b,
        final String c, String res) {
    // Base case: one of the string is empty
    if ((a.length() == 0) || (b.length() == 0) || (c.length() == 0)) {
        return res;
    }
    // Recursive case: find one common character
    else if ((a.charAt(0) == b.charAt(0)) && (b.charAt(0) == c.charAt(0))) {
        res += a.charAt(0);
        // Go to the next character
        final String r1 = recursive_lcs(a.substring(1), b.substring(1),
                c.substring(1), res);
        // Search if exists a longer sequence
        final String r2 = findMax(a, b, c, "");

        if (r2.length() > r1.length()) {
            return r2;
        } else {
            return r1;
        }
    }
    // Recursive case: no common character.
    else {
        // Check if is better the computed sequence, or if exists one better
        // forward
        final String c1 = findMax(a, b, c, "");
        if (c1.length() > res.length()) {
            return c1;
        } else {
            return res;
        }
    }
}

private static String findMax(final String a, final String b,
        final String c, final String res) {
    // Check all the possible combinations
    final String c1 = recursive_lcs(a, b, c.substring(1), res);
    final String c2 = recursive_lcs(a, b.substring(1), c, res);
    final String c3 = recursive_lcs(a.substring(1), b, c, res);
    if (c1.length() > c2.length()) {
        if (c1.length() > c3.length()) {
            return c1;
        } else {
            return c3;
        }
    } else {
        if (c2.length() > c3.length()) {
            return c2;
        } else {
            return c3;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
hel
```